# Can a Child component Access its Containing Component's Methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

I have seen similar questions to this but they are usually talking about a parent accessing a child component's methods or passing in methods through props. My question is on a specific situation, using `props.children`, and having any child component be able to call a method on the parent that is rendering `props.children`.

A simplified example of what im trying to achieve:

```
class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
}

handleInputChange(e){
    console.log("neat, you changed the input")
}

render() {
    return (
        <form>
            {this.props.children}
        </form>
    )
  }
}
```

And the component that is calling said component and passing in the children as props.

```
const Component = (props) => {
return(
    <WrapperComponent>
        <div className="form-group" >
            <label>
                <div>Text</div>
                <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} type={"text"}/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </WrapperComponent>
)
}
```

The idea is that I can render a component that holds certain logic, and pass in the elements as children for that component to render, but also  that the `props.children` can then call said logic within the wrapper, so I can pass in different children in different use cases, but the handling will always be the same. Is there a way to do this at all?

Comment: Just pass it to the child component via props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone your elements and add new props to them using some built-in React goodies:

```
class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
}

handleInputChange(e){
    console.log("neat, you changed the input")
}

render() {
    return (
        <form>
            {React.Children.map(
                this.props.children, 
                el => React.cloneElement(el, {onInputChange: this.handleInputChange})
            )}
        </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Then (remove WrapperComponent):

```
const Component = (props) => {
  return(
        <div className="form-group" >
            <label>
                <div>Text</div>
                <input onChange={props.onInputChange} type={"text"}/>
            </label>
        </div>
  )
}
```

Then:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <WrapperComponent><Component /></WrapperComponent>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: hey, this worked pretty well and i marked the answer as correct, but i do get an error in the console that says "Unknown event handler property `onInputChange`. It will be ignored". If within the cloneElement() function I write {onChange:this.handleInputChange} then it works, but it applies that event handler to every child component, ideally i would control this from the children using props, not just blindly applying it to all elements, since some children may have different handlers (for validation or submission)

Comment: ok i got it to work, it was very important to follow the last step, that renders the children as a component itself (<WrapperComponent><Component /></WrapperComponent>)or to just make sure that all the children (if just jsx) gets passed down within one container, I fixed it by wrapping the children content with a <React.Fragment>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way, but its not straightforward, and you may want to consider a different approach.

In order for a child component to have access to the methods of an arbitrary parent, the parent must override the child's props. This can be done using `React.cloneElement` in the `render()` function of the parent. In your example:

```
class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
}

handleInputChange(e){
    console.log("neat, you changed the input")
}

render() {
    return (
        <form>
            {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => (
                React.cloneElement(child, {handleInputChange: this.handleInputChange}
            )}
        </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Then, you can access the method in the child via `this.props.handleInputChange`.

Comment: thanks so much! you said you would suggest a different approach, is there a particular reason why this may be a bad approach other than its added complexity?

Comment: I'm mainly talking from a readability/maintainability point of view. When the behavior of a component is defined by an arbitrary container, it can be hard to understand what's going on.